# getting file creator/owner attributes in Java

Tags: java, posix

I am trying to read in a list of files and find the user who created the file.  With a *nix system, you can do something like

```
Map<String, Object> attrs = Files.readAttributes(Paths.get(filename), "posix:*");
```

However, when attempting it on a Windows system, I get an error because Windows is not able to access the POSIX properties.  You can get the "regular" (non POSIX) properties by doing this:

```
attrs = Files.readAttributes(Paths.get(filename), "*");
```

But the file's creator is not included in that list.

Is there any way to find out who created the file in a Java program running on Windows?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe on most OSs you can only get the current owner of the file rather than who created it. You might have to see if their is some sort of auditing on file changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use [`Files.getOwner(Path, LinkOption...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getOwner%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) to get the current owner (which may also be the creator) like

```
Path path = Paths.get("c:\\path\\to\\file.ext");
try {
    UserPrincipal owner = Files.getOwner(path, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
    String username = owner.getName();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> This should work if it is a *file system that supports [`FileOwnerAttributeView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileOwnerAttributeView.html). This file attribute view provides access to a file attribute that is the owner of the file*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FileOwnerAttributeView` to get the ***Owner*** info:

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("your_file_path_goes_here");
FileOwnerAttributeView ownerInfo = Files.getFileAttributeView(filePath,  FileOwnerAttributeView.class);
UserPrincipal fileOwner = ownerInfo.getOwner();
System.out.println("File Owned by: " + fileOwner.getName());
```